# Mapping for Different Type of Properties

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application I have a class which is extended by two other classes. Those two other classes are serialized in json and indexed on elasticsearch.

The problem I'm facing is that those two classes extending the first one present a property with same name but different types (one string and the other one object) as follows:

```
{
   "property1" : "a string",
   "property2" : "another string"
}

{
   "property1" : "this is ok as the first one is string too",
   "property2" : {
      "propertyFromProperty2" : "this is not ok"
   }
}
```

When indexing I receive following exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [property2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:418)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:517)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:517)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:517)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:517)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:363)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: unknown property [propertyFromProperty2]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateFieldForString(StringFieldMapper.java:331)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateField(StringFieldMapper.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:408)
```

what are my options here? I though maybe to use the field type with the name in order to avoid parsing errors, is this possible using elasticsearch?

Is there another solution therefore?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you cannot do that. After first indexing request, `property2` got the type `string`.

When you are attempting the second indexing request, you are basically trying to index the same `property2` but of [type `object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html#mapping-object-type).

This means different field types for the same field. This is not possible in Elasticsearch.

As options: make the first indexing request to match an `object` as well. Maybe something like this, but I don't know the specifics of your use case:

```
{
   "property1" : "a string",
   "property2" : {
      "something" : "another string"
   }
}
```